# R codes to call from TERR

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

I am trying to write code in TERR to call `r`, Kindly suggest me the list of packages that I can use.  I found `Rinr`, `SpotfireUtils`, `Sdatasets` are not available for download in `r` now, if anyone have the same kindly share it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question couldn't be more vague. Here's some good places to start.

- [TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R (TERR)](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-enterprise-runtime-for-r?_ga=1.40170859.815773750.1476827938)
- [TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R Technical Documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.3.0/doc/html/TIB_terr_Documentation/GUID-EC787EA6-DDCE-4DC8-A1B1-2A26A372A1ED.html) which has everything from compadibility to how-to install certain packages.